# How to access image generated from pdf file using react-pdf with pdf.worker.js

Tags: reactjs, pdf, svg, pdf.js, react-pdf

I am trying to load a PDF file as an image into a SVG within D3.js, and using React. I have managed to use react-pdf to load the pdf file as a dom element. Through the network tab, I see that 'pdf.worker.js' has generated a blob as a jpeg image at a URL (possibly using createObjectURL). I want to access this jpeg image, but I don't know how to, and I haven't found an answer.

[https://imgur.com/PuSSJqC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W23g.jpg)

Can anyone help me please?

I tried getting accessing the canvas element directly from the DOM and using `importPDFCanvas.toDataURL()`, but this image is blank.

```
onDocumentLoadSuccess = () => {
  const importPDFCanvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.querySelector('.import-pdf-page canvas');
  const pdfAsImageSrc = importPDFCanvas.toDataURL();
};

<Document file={importPDF.pdfSrc}>
  <Page 
    className="import-pdf-page"
    onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoadSuccess}
    pageNumber={1}
  />
</Document>;
```

I expect there to be a way to access this image or the URL through the pdf.js api, but have no idea how to get it. Sorry if this seems like a newbie question, would appreciate any guidance on where to look or what to look for!

*Edit:*
Solution was just to use `onRenderSuccess` instead of `onLoadSuccess`.

Comment: You should be able to easily get the image by doing `toDataURL()` on the PDF canvas. In fact I just tested it with PDF.js and it works. So there is probably something going wrong there. Please post the code you are using to grab the canvas element and generate an image.

Comment: Since I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf, I'm getting dom elements like this screenshot:
https://imgur.com/2y2cspc
Using .toDataURL() on this canvas element gives an empty image, I think it's the way the library works. 

I will try using pdf.js directly or this library instead.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf-js

Comment: Turns out I just needed to use `onRenderSuccess` instead of `onLoadSuccess`, as the canvas image was not rendered at that time. Obvious solution!

Comment: Ah I see. That's why I asked you to post the code you used to grab the image. ;) If you solved your own problem it would be helpful for you to post an answer to your own question below in case anyone in the future has a similar problem!

Comment: I don't seem to have the option to post an answer, perhaps I don't have the reputation for it yet. I've added the solution at the bottom of the original post in case it helps others.